# mobileservicesynctable pullasync fails when using contains on list of more than 14 entries

Tags: linq, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

The code below fails and the err exception is triggered - only if the list of rounds has more than 14 entries in it. I have validated the individual strings in the list and the data is correct.

The error message is : The request could not be completed.  (Not Found)
What am I missing here? 
Is there an alternative to contains?

```
try
        {
            await App.MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();

            List<string> rounds = App.RoundsViewModel.roundItems.Select(r => r.id).Distinct().ToList();

            await ScoresTable.PullAsync("Scores", ScoresTable.Where(x => rounds.Contains(x.RoundID)));
        }
        catch (MobileServicePushFailedException ex)
        { }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(err.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Would you please the detail log returned by the server side?

Comment: Do you mean what's generated in the output window? If not, can you give me an idea how to get the info you requested.

Comment: You can get the detail log from server side by debugging or Postman.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I assume, its detailed error log on the app service with azure? Can you advise how to get this?

Comment: Can anybody help with this?